# Can't call actionListener of PrimeFaces commandButton from a composite component

Tags: jakarta-ee, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a composite component inside another composite component. The **Inner** component has a `p:commandButton` that is bound to an `actionListener`, it looks like that:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
          xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
          xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
          xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
          xmlns:cc="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite"
          xmlns:uv="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/components/views/core">
    <cc:interface>
        <cc:attribute name="organizationController" type="core.components.OrganizationController" required="true"/>
    </cc:interface>
    <cc:implementation>
        <uv:organizationDataSearch id="srcOrganization343423"
                                   controller="#{cc.attrs.organizationController}"
                                   title="testOutter"/>
    </cc:implementation>
    </html>
```

And my uv:organizationDataSearch's piece of code is

```
        <cc:interface>
    ...
        <cc:attribute name="controller" type="core.components.OrganizationController" required="true"/>
    ...
        </cc:interface>
         <cc:implementation>

        ...
                <p:outputPanel id="searchPanel" ...>
                    <p:outputPanel id="searchPanel" styleClass="searchPanel">
        <!--search fields with using of h:inputText -->

                        <p:commandButton id="searchButton"
                                         value="Search"
                                         actionListener="#{cc.attrs.controller.search(true)}"
                                         process="searchPanel, @this"
                                         update="searchResultPanel"
                                         styleClass="searchButton" />
                    </p:outputPanel>
..        
    <p:outputPanel id="searchResultPanel" layout="block" styleClass="searchResultPanel">
    <p:dataTable id="searchResultTable" .../>
    </p:outputPanel>
...
         </cc:implementation>
```

Where `cc.attrs.controller.search(true)` is a method in `core.components.OrganizationController` with the following signature

```
public void search(Boolean isInnSearch) {...}
```

**PrimeFaces** that I use has **3.0th** version.
**JSF** implelementation is the 2.0th **mojarra**

The problem is in the point of the `actionListener (cc.attrs.controller.search(true))`, this  one is not called when I try to search data. The interesting moment is that everything works fine when I use `h:commandButton` instead or if I use the **inner** composite component inside of a simple **composition** component. 
Who knows what is the problem here?

Comment: When I understand you right, the method is not called at all. For curiosity: Can you test it with a method `public void search() {...}` and calling the actionListener like a JavaBean `actionListener="#{cc.attrs.controller['search']}"` ?

Comment: Okay, don't see any real reason for that. Add a component to the `update`, that holds something like a `h:messages`-tag. This way you would notice if a converter-error or similar occurs and this way blocks the method from being called (JSF lifecycle). Also I would check (as p:commandButton is AJAX) e.g. FireBug for the server-response of the clicked button. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try to debug with it) It seems that the "execute" is called in the wrong way. I have just debugged and I got the following result: the "execute" phase is ended up with the Restore View Phase and after that go to the Render Responce Phase. In the same moment there were not any messages on p:messages.